# django - how to query this?

Tags: python, django

i have two tables called Location and Rate.

Rate table has these items:[image]

von_location is Foreignkey to Location table.

i want to get a location for a wanted rate. if i search for a location with romantic `2`, i am getting location with id `5`. this is fine. but if i also search for a location with romantic `3`, i am also getting the location with id `5`. but i want this logic:

if one locations have two rates, get the latest one. how can i do this in django?

my models are:

```
class Location(models.Model):
 name = models.TextField()
 adres = models.TextField()

class Rate(models.Model):
 von_location = models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name='locations_bewertung')
 bewertung = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
 romantic = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
 priceleistung = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
 datum = DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
```

i dropped some columns which are not relevant to my question

i tried this:

```
locations = Location.objects.filter(**s_kwargs).order_by('locations_bewertung').distinct('locations_bewertung')
```

i am still getting the same location for both queries. `2`, and `3`.

Comment: Could you show the models?

Comment: @alecxe, yes, pls c my update

Comment: cr and von_user_id are not covered with your models, although they appear in the database.

Comment: @Tadeck, as you read in my question, i dropped some columns as they are not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused about whether you're trying to filter on `Location` or `Rate`. Your introduction implies that you want to filter on `Rate` (since `romantic` belongs to that model) but your sample query is filtering on `Location`.

If you want to find the `Location` of the most recent `Rate` associated with a set of query parameters, try something like:

```
location = Rate.objects.filter(romantic=something).latest('datum').von_location
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to add a function to the Location model, like this:

```
def get_latest_rate(self):
    return self.rate_set.latest('datum')
```

Then you can do this:

```
[l.get_latest_rate() for l in Location.objects.filter(**s_kwargs)]
```